# Spring and Kafka streams - How to use Query API

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm new to kafka and kafka streams. I have a working basic Spring service with kafka producer, consumer, KStream and KTable. Now, I would like to check my KTable records, so in order to achive it I'm tring to work with the Kafka Query API.

This can be achived by the following (without the Spring integration):

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
// Get access to the custom store
MyReadableCustomStore<String,String> store = streams.store("the-custom-store", new MyCustomStoreType<String,String>());
// Query the store
String value = store.read("key");
```

Now, I tried to work with the Spring based InteractiveQueryService in order to query.. but I faied with some dependencied issues in Spring boot.

What is the best approach for using the kafka query API in Spring?

The Spring kafka config in my service looks like:

```
@Bean("streamsBuilder")
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean recordsStreamBuilderFactoryBean() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    // set some properties
    return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(config));
}
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Spring Boot app to show how...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class So58918956Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58918956Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CountDownLatch latch(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFB) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        streamsBuilderFB.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
            if (State.RUNNING.equals(newState)) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        return latch;
    }

    @Bean
    public KTable<String, String> table(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        Serde<String> serde = Serdes.String();
        KTable<String, String> table = streamsBuilder.table("so58918956",
                Consumed.with(serde, serde)
                        .withOffsetResetPolicy(AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST), 
                Materialized.as("the-custom-store"));
        return table;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFB,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, KTable<String, String> table) {

        return args -> {
            template.send("so58918956", "key", "value");
            latch(streamsBuilderFB).await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> store = streamsBuilderFB.getKafkaStreams().store(
                    table.queryableStoreName(),
                    QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
            System.out.println(store.get("key"));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so58918956").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is not how to define KStream, but how can I query a store of KTable with Spring?.

Comment: I have some basic KTable with a store definition and I would like to run a quey on this store, from some REST controller and to check the store data. Any ideas how can I do it.. or maybe you have other idea to view the store data

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your help! that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Gary is there any document from Spring website? The reference is very short.

Comment: @Gary where is the bean declaration of "streamsBuilderFB"? I copied your code and it is null in my code.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#streams-config You need `@EnableKafkaStreams` to trigger the creation of that bean.